# Matrices and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $M$ be an arbitrary real $2\times2$ matrix.
>
> Show that if $x(t)$ $\land$ $y(t)$ $\in$ $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and that if $a(t)$ $\land$ $b(t)$ $\in$ $C^0(\mathbb{R})$, then the following system of differential equations is linear:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
>         x\,'(t)\\
>         y\,'(t)\\
>         \end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{M}\begin{bmatrix}
>         x(t)\\
>         y(t)\\
>         \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
>         a(t)\\
>         b(t)\\
>         \end{bmatrix}$$

I'm new to the subject. Hints to how I proceed?

Comment: In most texts your equation will be called *linear*, it is not a matter of showing that it is. True that it is not appropriate to call it linear (since the set of solutions need not be a linear space), but that's what is in use.

Comment: I'm aware, but here I'm asked to show it.

Comment: Well, usually the definition is indeed: an equation is said to be linear if it is of the form ... (your form). So, either you tells us your definition (if different) or you will need to ask what is the meaning of the question. :)